# Getting the datagrid row value

Tags: jquery, html, datagrid

I searched all over the net, but i think my code is specific...I want to simply select the row and get the value from the row i clicked...i tryed several things but none worked.. someone could give me a little help? Im trying to get the "nome" column value..

```
$('#dataTable tbody').click(function (event) {
    //alert($(this).attr('nome')); //trying to alert id of the clicked row          

});
```

and my table is:

```
<table id="dataTable" class="datagrid">         
        <thead class="tabela1">
            <th field="nome" class="tabela1">Nome</th>
            <th field="senha" class="tabela1">Senha</th>
            <th field="telefone" class="tabela1">Telefone</th>
            <th field="email" class="tabela1">Email</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="tabela1"></tbody>
    </table>
```

but im doing a jquery code to fill the table:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url;
    var url_save="save_users.php";
    $("#dataTable tbody").html("");
    $.getJSON("get_users.php",function(data){
    $.each(data.users, function(i,user){
    var newRow =
    "<tr>"
    +"<td>"+user.nome+"</td>"
    +"<td>"+user.senha+"</td>"
    +"<td>"+user.telefone+"</td>"
    +"<td>"+user.email+"</td>"
    +"</tr>" ;
    $(newRow).appendTo("#dataTable tbody");
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dataTable td').click(function(){
    //alert($(this).attr('nome')); //trying to alert id of the clicked row          
    window.alert($(this).val());
});
```

What does this say? And can you make a jsfidlle? In your jsfille use your table that is generated by the jquery. So just paste the HTML in there, not the database connection, because that's not helpful for us..